# GGplot with multiple/conditional scale_fill_manual for stat_density_ridges

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a question for ggplot experts...

My dataset has 432000 observations of 4 variables (one is numeric, the others are factors). `Predictors` has 6 levels, `Estimate` has 4 levels, `Model` has 2 levels. `Value` has a max of 2.6 and a min of -3. (I hope you can create data with that information.)

The plot set-up is a 4x6 faceted plot [here's is a 2x3 example of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWS2W.png):

- each row is a different level of a factor (`Predictors`)
- each column a different level of another factor (`Estimate`)
- there are two distributions within each mini-plot which is another factor (`Model`)

The goal is to plot:

- the distributions in each column in a different color (blue, green, red, yellow) (according to `Estimate`)
- within each mini-plot, the shade/hue of that color should be different (e.g., within the green column, repeat the order of colors according to `Model`)
- fill the tails of two quantiles on each distribution of each mini-plot (as the tail lines in the picture indicate; color the tail from each line to the end of the tail in black/gray). The tails can be the same throughout the entire plot.

Here's an example of the code that I'm using. It doesn't plot the quantiles in a separate color:

```
pp <- ggplot(dd, aes(x=Value, y=as.factor(Model), fill=factor(Model))) + 
stat_density_ridges(quantile_lines = TRUE, quantiles = c(0.05, 0.95), alpha = 0.95,vline_size = 0.5)+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "white")) +
geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", color = "black", size=0.5) +
  facet_grid(Predictors~Estimate, scales = "free") + labs(x="Parameter value", y=" ") +
   theme(text = element_text(size = 16)) + theme(axis.title=element_text(face="bold"),  strip.text = element_text(
        size = 16)) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

To color the quantiles, you can swap `fill=factor(Model)` with `fill=factor(..quantile..)`, but getting both "fills" in the same plot has been impossible thus far. Among many other things, I tried entering multiple factors into "fill", like this: `fill=c(factor(Model), factor(Estimate), ..quantile..)` , but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to look into the ggnewscale package

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think from your description your data looks a bit like this (though I've limited it to 6000 rows):

```
set.seed(69)

Value      <- rnorm(6000)
Predictors <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:6], each = 1000))
Estimate   <- factor(rep(rep(letters[1:4], each = 250), 6))
Model      <- factor(rep(rep(c("Model1", "Model2"), each = 125), 24))

Value <- Value + rep(rnorm(6), each = 1000)
Value <- Value + rep(rep(rnorm(4), each = 250), 6)
Value <- Value + rep(rep(rnorm(2), each = 125), 24)

dd <- data.frame(Value, Predictors, Estimate, Model)
```

It sounds like most of what you want to do can be achieved by creating a new factor variable that is a conjunction of two other factors:

```
dd$fill_factor <- as.factor(paste0(Model, Estimate))
```

Which means that we should get close to the desired effect with minimal changes to your code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

my_colors <- c("#0000FF", "#00FF00", "#FF0000", "#FFFF00")

ggplot(dd, aes(x = Value, y = Model, fill = fill_factor)) + 
  stat_density_ridges(quantile_lines = TRUE, 
                      quantiles = c(0.05, 0.95), 
                      alpha = 0.95,
                      vline_size = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(gsub("0", "6", my_colors),
                               gsub("F", "A", my_colors))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(Predictors ~ Estimate, scales = "free") + 
  labs(x = "Parameter value", y = " ") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),  
        strip.text = element_text(size = 16),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: That is almost what I am looking for...The only thing that is missing is the colored quantiles (gray). For example, A-a-model1 should have gray tails (the quantiles).